# Sufficient condition for a seminorm to be "bounded".

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $X$ be a Banach space, and $p$ a seminorm on $X$ with the following property : for all sequences $(x_n)_n$ of elements of $X$ such that both $\sum x_n$ and $\sum p(x_n)$ converge (in $X$ and $\mathbb R$), the inequality
> $$p\left(\sum_{n \ge 1}x_n\right) \le \sum_{n\ge 1} p(x_n)$$
> holds. Show that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all $x \in E$, $p(x) \le C||x||$

Since $p$ is a seminorm, we may as well only look at elements $x \in X$ with $||x|| \le 1$. I managed to show that $Y := p^{-1}(\{0\})$ is a subspace of $X$, and - using the condition on $p$ - that it is closed, meaning that you can work in the quotient $X/Y$, which is still a Banach space, and assume that $p$ is a norm, but I'm not sure this helps. I tried using Baire's theorem, since $p^{-1}([0,n])$ has an empty interior, but I haven't been able to prove (and am not sure that) it is closed. I also managed to prove that should the conclusion be false, you can construct a discontinuous linear functional $f : E \to \mathbb R$ with $|f| \le p$, but it has not proven useful yet.

I don't think that the exercise is too hard, I might just be struggling to remember my theorems correctly. If you have any ideas or insights, I'd love to hear them.